# Is my stepson being exposed to something inappropriate?

Tags: behavior, co-parenting

My step son is 5 years old and spends most of his time with his biological mom. We don't agree with a lot of the things she does but I have never though there was anything not good going on. However, a few weeks ago he was watching my hubby play a video game. He said he liked the girl characters boobs and that he wanted to put his wiener on them. More recently he told me that after his dad went to work he wanted me to pull my pants down and sit on his head. I feel like this is not normal for his age and I'm wondering if he is being exposed to something inappropriate at his mom's. Am I wrong? Is this normal for a 5 year old?

Comment: Welcome!  I encourage you to look around at other similiar questions while you wait for an answer.  Some that look similiar to yours are: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10712 and https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/6283

Comment: If it was "normal", you would not be worried. When in doubt, it's prudent to consult a specialist. If there isn't any helpful information in the duplicate's answers, flag a mod and we'll review why you think this is sufficiently different to merit its being reopened, but I think, even without the forcefulness, the behavior is still highly unusual. Thanks!

Comment: It's not normal but I'd there a reason why you think it would have come from his mother, is it possible it could have come from friends at school or anywhere else. Would be prudent to be sure before accusing.

Comment: Hopefully it's from some punk/twerp who got it from an ignorant older sibling.  I remember when I was quite young I was the most foul-mouthed SOB on the playground, because I ran with older siblings and their friends.  Had no idea what it meant, and it probably sounded like gibberish, but I knew that's how older kids who were rebels talked, or so I thought.  Hope that's the case with your child - acting out for the payback of getting attention, and not something more serious.  Definitely needs looking into, though.